# Remember chatwindow state by cookie in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

How to create and update cookies by the state of the chat windows?
I want to display the chat windows on page as they are in use by users when page reload.
If the chat window is minimized show it in minimize state.Like this i want to create and set cookies.
I want to store the state and id of the chat windows which are open,minimized.
 I am using the toggle function to minimize and maximize  chat windows.Can anyone have the idea ,how to do this in j query cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You could store everything in one cookie:

$_COOKIES["chatwindows"] = "john@example.com:1;mike@example.com:0";

john@example.com represents the users with which the users is talking to, and 1 represents the windows state, in this case 1 = opened.

You just have to parse/split the cookie content correctly.